# Cmake: how can I generate <Project>Targets-<configuration>.cmake file? (eg. MyLibTargets-debug.cmake)

Tags: cmake

Title says it all. How can I generate `<Project>Targets-<configuration>.cmake` file? By which command? (Note: by configuration I mean content of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable, ie. debug, release etc.

---

Note: I know that `install(EXPORT fooTargets FILE "FooTargets.cmake" DESTINATION lib/foo)` (where `foo` is my custom library and `fooTargets` are exported values from `install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooTargets ...)`) creates basic `<Project>Targets.cmake` file, but it also requires the configuration/build type file and I cannot find more information about it.

---

**Update**

It looks like this file is generated with the install(EXPORT ...) command, but in Windows version of cpack is bug which omits it when `cpack` is run. I'll do more research when I have the time and then post the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `FILE` suboption:

```
install(EXPORT fooTargets DESTINATION lib/foo)
```

From [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainstall):

```
By default the generated file will be called <export-name>.cmake but the FILE
option may be used to specify a different name.
```

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/forexample/package-example

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't idea about the project, too bad I didn't find it at monday, it would save me a lots of days of research.

However, it does not solve my problem. Removing FILE sub-option won't solve anything, it just simply change name. I used it only because of letter-case normalization. `install(EXPORT ...)` still generates file `*Target.cmake` like usual and `*Target-<config>.cmake` only sometimes, i.e. when I call `make install DESTDIR=./foo` it does, but not when I call `cpack -G ZIP`. So I'm still searching for direct way how to generate `*.Target-<config>.cmake` files directly...

Comment: So if I add at the end of CMakeFiles.txt "`include(CPack)`", result is still same - after calling `cpack -G ZIP` whole project is packed, it includes everything except the damned `*Target-<config>.cmake` file which makes it useless if I want to export the project to someone who also uses cmake and want's to use my libraries...

Comment: Good work :). Anyway, about the new question - I already did created it - in fact, I did it before writing this one. In that one I ask about the problem with cpack and when it looked like nobody knows or uses cpack for that reason, I created this question which is only about cmake and the `*Target-<config>.cmake` file. (Btw. answer to this one solves the other one, but not vice versa). (Btw. I know I could just use `make install DESTDIR=./my_dir` and then pack it, but cpack can create nice installers, so I would like to use that functionality...)

Comment: Ah, I finally got some time at home where I use Linux (Ubuntu) (until now I was under Windows 7) and I found that here `cpack` creates the config target file... I'll do some more research with the most recent version of cmake/cpack, but it looks like Widows cpack bug.

Comment: Note about your example project: I guess you never run it on Linux - it works, but it needs to fix two things: `include(cpack)` must be `include(CPack)` and `add_library(foo foo.cpp)` must be `add_library(foo Foo.cpp)` (or rename `Foo.cpp` to `foo.cpp`). Linux is case-sensitive and couldn't run these lines.

Comment: Np :). About cpack - in that case, sorry, I guess I added it myself to test it and forget to clean